# Display external webpage into a webpage in my application

Tags: java, javascript, html, jakarta-ee, iframe

i want to display an external webpage (exactly as it's rendered in that site) into a webpage in my application in a way that's fast and better for SEO crawlers, and i was wondering if there's a way to do that with javaee ?
if not then what is better in performance and for SEO the **XMLHTTPRequest** way or the **iframes** way.

please advise with sample code or link if possible, thanks

Update: example website is: http://www.akhbarak.net/

Comment: I don't think that web crawlers execute JavaScript (`XMLHttpRequest`), so they would understand `iframe`s better.

Comment: This sounds distinctly unethical, if not positively a breach of copyright. Could you give some sort of use case explaining why you want SEO crawlers to index the external content as coming from your page?

Comment: @Andrew Leach, i want to make something like this website http://www.akhbarak.net/

Comment: I don't read Arabic, I'm afraid, so I can't offer any other opinion.

Comment: What do you mean by "better for SEO"? That the crawler detects where the content originally comes from?

Comment: @Andrew Leach, when you click on any news link you will find that it embed the news page from other website.

Comment: @Bergi, if you took a look about the sample website you will find that it post a link to the original news with the same title, and when you click on the link it will embed the news page from other website, if you tried to search for this news in google you will find that this extracting website appears first and the original comes later.

Comment: That description confirms my view: it is unethical and almost certainly a breach of copyright. I know the answer about how to do it and get a search engine to index the content as yours, but [I am forbidden to give it](http://www.bcs.org/category/6030).

Comment: @Andrew Leach, why it's unethical, since i embed the news from the original website and refer to it ?

Comment: I consider it unethical because someone else's content is being indexed as coming from your site. That means that following the search result to your site shows *your* advertising and other content, not the originator's. Just because you provide a link to the other site does not make it OK: you are still effectively pirating it. (It's rather like rebroadcasting a radio station, but replacing all the originator's "This is Radio KLJW" jingles with "This is Radio WTFX with content from KLJW" -- how would that be acceptable?)

Comment: Note: it's entirely up to you whether you go ahead and do this. But you need to be aware that it may come with consequences. Part of my Code of Conduct (linked earlier) means that not only must I not help you pirate other people's content, I mustn't help you to heap burning coals on your own head by doing so.

Comment: -1, in order to index content on your website, you must subscribe to their RSS feed or get access to their API, more over in future they will block embedding by simply sending no embed header and modern browsers will not display content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to display content from different pages inline, use [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe) (iframe stands for inline frame - it has nothing to do with Apple).

If you'd like to use AJAX to display pages, I would recommend [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox).

Note that accessing pages in a different domain via AJAX is next to impossible - this is a very, very big security hole. I would not recommend doing it. You would have to use a proxy on your own server to fetch the page and return its HTML.

That said, using the iframe in your source code, so it is loaded with the rest of the page, seems like your best bet. Sites like facebook and twitter use this in embeddable "like" and "tweet" widgets so that those widgets can make requests on their own domain - that is, twitter or facebook. While managing lots of iframes isn't very fun, it is a very accepted way of doing what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you could

- load the whole page into a PHP variable,
- replace the body tags with ,
- take out the html tags,
- pull out the entire  section and put it in the encompassing pages ,
- and replace all links with absolute ones (ie '/images' changes to 'http://example.com/images')

Would it be easy to do? Probably not. It's the only way I can think of to accomplish it so that the site appears as part of yours though.